# Как отправить переменную на функцию в классе?

Tags: python, классы

Немного запутался в классах Python. Допустим у нас есть класс:

```
class Hello:
    def hi(self, h2): #можно ли так?
        print(h2)

h1 = Hello()
h1.hi(“Hello, idiot”)
```

Перейдет ли переменная которую я ввел в self?

И второй вопрос:
Иногда в скобках функций пишут вот так:

```
def hi(resource: dict)
```

Что это значит? Типа уточняют какой тип данных?

Comment: *«Немного запутался в классах Python.»* По-видимому, вы затем ничего о классах не знаете. Лучше бы было сначала взять учебник Питона.

Comment: Две разные темы в одном вопросе. Это неправильно. Должно задать два отдельных вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

А в чём сложность взять и проверить? Просто добавляете `print(self)` и запускаете ваш код (только пришлось поменять кавычки, они у вас какие-то не питоновские):

```
class Hello:
    def hi(self, h2):
        print(self)
        print(h2)

h1 = Hello()
h1.hi("Hello, idiot")
```

Вывод:

```
<__main__.Hello object at 0x7fe72b88b4d0>
Hello, idiot
```

Резюме:

1. Так можно, код работает.
2. Ваша переменная попала в `h2`
3. В `self` попала ссылка на экземпляр класса `Hello`, т.е. на вашу переменную `h1`, от которой вы вызвали этот метод `hi`.

P.S.

```
def hi(resource: dict)
```

> Что это значит? Типа уточняют какой тип данных?

Да, это "аннотация типов" - попытка сделать Питон типизированным языком.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)